# Click event handlers no longer working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I spend the half night finding the error, but I give up. This is my problem.
On my site, click events doesn't work anymore. About three days ago, everything worked just fine. I made no changes besides some notations ( //...).

URL: no needed anymore.

Normally, the card zooms in on dblclick. 
And all the buttons in the upper, left control field should work too (after one zoom). ;)

I added a test div on the left side, just a DIV:

```
<div id="blab">TEST</div>
```

And for the JS part...

```
$("#blab").click(function () {
    alert("test");
});
```

Easy and simple, but it doesn't work too. I bet, its something really stupid, bit I don't have an idea. ;(
I tried it with "on." or "live." too. ... same result

I hope someone has a good tip for me.

Thanks in advance.

Edit/Update:

Thanks for all your help. I was just to tired to see the difference. The live version has no active markers o the map, so  have this little "null" error. I consider the suggestions made for this error, but maybe i change this part completely.

Thousand thanks to you all. You helped a blind man seeing again the beauty of code. ;)

Comment: Check browser console, any errors? Is jQuery loaded correctly?

Comment: In Firebug, did you see any error in console. I think some of the javascript function is failing/throwing error before this call.

Comment: i can see an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"

Comment: I see *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"*. You seem to be passing a `null` object to the `Map` constructor

Comment: This is the offending caller of that Map constructor: `$.each(param, function(idx, obj){
  Geo(obj);
 });` param is null.

Comment: *"I made no changes besides some notations"*. I call shenanigans on this one. I bet you also updated jQuery recently

Comment: Yeah, the errror was there before, I think, not sure anymore. I erase this error first I guess.. stupid me. And Phil, no, I changed it yesterday, hoping it changes something. ;) It was the same since a few month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your index page you have the following:

```
var obj = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var map = new Map(obj);
});
```

Then in map.js you have this:

```
$.each(param, function(idx, obj){ Geo(obj); });
```

param is null (passed in as null).

Answer (score 0):

i can see an error in http://dbl76.beuth-hochschule.de/~karte/

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null".

Are you checking any elements length?, before checking the length, include the condition

```
if (element != null) 
{
  //access the value of element length
}
```

And also, are you adding

```
$("#blab").click(function () {
    alert("test");
});
```

in document.ready(), i couldn't see the code included in the website.. when i try in browser console. it works fine. Which browser you are using?

Comment: Clatest verson of chome, firefox and opera, IE9

Answer (score 0):

Apart from passing `null` into your `Map` constructor (which causes an error via jQuery's `.each()` method), you are using jQuery version 1.10.2.

Your `map.js` script uses the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method which was removed in jQuery 1.9. You need to switch to using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

I'd also clean up that `null` reference. Something like this perhaps

```
var obj = {}; // you had null here
$(document).ready(function() {
    var map = new Map(obj);
});
```

Comment: Jeah switched back to an older one, 1.8.1 for now. Funny fact, it works on my localhost now, with out the null error, live version still wont ^^;

Answer (score 0):

I'm also getting *TypeError: e is undefined* when scrolling the map. I think the problem comes when you call stopWheel function (using Firefox).

```
m.viewingBox.hover(function() {
        $(document).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',function(){ 
            stopWheel(); 
        });
    }, function() {
        $(document).unbind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll');
    });


function stopWheel(e){
        if(!e || typeof e == "undefined"){ /* IE7, IE8, Chrome, Safari */ 
            e = window.event; 
        }
        if(e.preventDefault) { /* Chrome, Safari, Firefox */ 
            e.preventDefault(); 
        } 
        e.returnValue = false; /* IE7, IE8 */
    }
```